# ImageMagick: What is this convert-command doing?

Tags: php, ruby, imagemagick

I'm trying to port a PHP script to Ruby and until now I only used ImageMagick to convert from one file-format to another. Meaning: Yes, I'm an ImageMagick newbie. ;-)

Somewhere inside the PHP script the following code is executed:

```
$output = array();
$returnValue = 0;
$cmd = 'convert '.$pngFile->path.' -resize 1x1 -alpha on -channel o -format "%[fx:u.a]" info:'
exec($cmd, $output, $returnValue);
```

Using the ImageMagick [documentation for convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) I identified the following options:

- `-resize 1x1` Resize to 1x1 pixels (right?)
- `-alpha on` Activate alpha-channel
- `-channel o` Apply options to the opacity image-channel

My questions:

1. What does `-format "%[fx:u.a]"` exactly do? I know that `u` is a symbol for *first image in sequence* and `a` one for *alpha*. But I don't get what the whole expression really does.
2. What does `info:` stand for?
3. What does this convert-command exactly do?

Thank you very much for your kind help.

**Please note**: The accepted answer on the following question has a very good answer to this question:

[Understanding ImageMagick's convert and translating to Ruby RMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4132787/61427)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like it is computing the average opacity. The `info` format is a dummy image format that will instruct convert to output image information to stdout (`:` means stdout) in the format `%[fx:u.a]`. Resizing to 1x1 is probably a way of averaging.