# RMagick remove white background from image and make it transparent

Tags: ruby, image, imagemagick, image-manipulation, rmagick

I need to remove the white background from this image and make the background transparent. So it's just a black tick on the transparent background exported as a png.

e.g. Turn

[image]

Into

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`convert image.png -matte -fill none -fuzz 1% -opaque white  result.png`

Replaces anything white with transparency. The fuzz option includes anything that is almost-white.

Comment: @hadees this looks like a good start: [Understanding ImageMagick's convert and translating to Ruby RMagick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132787/understanding-imagemagicks-convert-and-translating-to-ruby-rmagick)

Answer (score 4):

I know I am pretty late to the party, but a lot has changed since this question was first posted, so here is how you can do it today using at least version `2.15.4` of `rmagick`

Assuming you have the image somewhere accessible:

```
image = Magick::Image.new(path_to_file)
image.background_color = 'none'
```

If you also want to trim the image so it's only as big as it boundaries, simply use `.trim!`

```
image.trim!
```

EDIT:

Turns out the solution above does not really work for all use cases. A more general solution is this:

```
# the image needs to be in 'PNG' format
image.format = 'PNG'

# set a fuzz on the image depending on how accurate you want to be
image.fuzz = '10%'

# get the image background color
background_color = image.background_color

# convert pixels based on their color to being transparent
# the fuzz set above controls how accurate the conversion will be
image.paint_transparent(background_color)
```

Answer (score 1):

With v6.8.4-Q16 using the below command:

```
convert nike.png -matte -fill none -fuzz 1% -opaque white nikeOutput.png
```

Results in:

[image]

Here is the command I use:

```
convert nike.jpg -transparent white NikeProd.png
```

[image]

[image]