# Reading UTF-8 text files with ReadList

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to use `ReadList` to read UTF-8 (or any other) encoded text files using `ReadList[..., Word]`, or is it ASCII-only?  If it's ASCII-only, is it possible to "fix" the encoding of the already read data with good performance (i.e. preserving the performance advantages of `ReadList` over `Import`)?

<sub>`Import[..., CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]` works but it's quite a bit slower than `ReadList`.  `$CharacterEncoding` has no effect on `ReadList`</sub>

[Download a sample UTF-8 encoded file here.](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ZdMTBWnT)

For testing performance on a large input, see the test file in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247005/efficiently-working-with-and-generating-large-text-files).

---

Here are the timings of the answers on a large-ish text file:

**Import**

```
In[2]:= Timing[
 data = Import[file, "Text"];
 ]

Out[2]= {5.234, Null}
```

**Heike**

```
In[4]:= Timing[
 data = ReadList[file, String];
 FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[data], "UTF8"];
 ]

Out[4]= {4.328, Null}
```

**Mr. Wizard**

```
In[5]:= Timing[
 string = FromCharacterCode[BinaryReadList[file], "UTF-8"];
 ]

Out[5]= {2.281, Null}
```

Comment: Would you link to a UTF-8 encoded file I can use to test, please?

Comment: As I recall `ToCharacterCode` natively handles lists, so I don't think `Map` is needed.  Does that improve its performance at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I leave out `Word`, this works:

```
$CharacterEncoding = "UTF-8";

ReadList["UTF8.txt"]
```

*This however is a failure, because the data is not read as strings.*

#### Please try this on a larger file and report its performance:

```
FromCharacterCode[BinaryReadList["UTF8.txt"], "UTF-8"]
```

Comment: ["Shamelessly stealing from each other to arrive to the best possible solution"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041703/remove-white-background-from-an-image-and-make-it-transparent) :-)  Who shall I award the answer to? ;-)

Comment: Your first version fooled me too.  I really need to turn on showing those quotation marks ...

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work

```
FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[ReadList["raw.php.txt", Word]], "UTF-8"]
```

The timings I get for the linked test file are

```
FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[ReadList["test.txt", Word]], "UTF-8"]); // Timing

(* ==> {0.000195, Null} *)

Import["test.txt", "Text"]; // Timing

(* ==> {0.01784, Null} *)
```

Comment: Thanks!  And indeed, `To/FromCharacterCode` was the key!  (See the other answer and my edit with the timings.)

Comment: @Szabolcs and Heike, I did not see this answer, even after I posted my update!  I even refreshed the page in impatience to see if Szabolcs had tried my new answer.  Perhaps I am that blind, but it seems like a glitch.  Sorry for any toes I trod on.

Comment: As I think about it I've been using a script blocker (NoScript).  I'll bet it interfered with the page update somehow.