# Giving an image a black background?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, opencv

Is there any way of removing a white background and turning it into black in MATLAB?

Say i have this image:

[image]

I get the following output when i apply the code suggested in the answer: Which isn't perfect

[image]

Comment: It took me a while to realise that this was actually a fruit, and not some sort of computer-generated image of a lava planet. I think I need to turn off the Star Trek and go eat something healthy for once.

Comment: Can't you iterate through the image pixels and change all the white pixels to black?

Comment: @PulkitGoyal i think that could be done

Comment: Check this question and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041703/remove-white-background-from-an-image-and-make-it-transparent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem, as Andrey noticed, is that not all background pixels are "255 white". This probably is happening due to JPEG compression algorithm and also because there's a shadow of the fruit in the image.

To solve this problem, first get a binary mask of the fruit region by blurring the image (this is necessary to overcome the JPEG artifacts) and then threshold the image with a very high value, but a little lower than 255. Here's the solution in Matlab:

```
I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p4jV.jpg'); % Load your image.
H = fspecial('gaussian'); % Create the filter kernel.
I = imfilter(I,H); % Blur the image.

Mask = im2bw(Ig, 0.9); % Now we are generating the binary mask.
I([Mask, Mask, Mask]) = 0; % Now we have the image.
```

Here's the output (you can also try different threshold values in im2bw):

[image]

Comment: Good post (+1). By the way, it doesn't have to be due to JPEG compression. If it is a natural image of fruit on white table, any digital camera nowadays does this kind of effect.

Comment: On cameras this also happens because of JPEG compression. In professional or semi-profession cameras, however, you can choose to save the photos with no compression (also knows as raw format). Then you don't get that kind of effect.

Comment: Even in RAW images with custom processing to Bitmap you will get it. It is a natural property of optics and sensor limitation (Check out about MTF/PSF) - http://www.imatest.com/docs/sharpness/

Comment: Not to mention the noise that will be on the white background and will cause some of the white pixels become almost white.

Answer (score 2):

You fail due to the anti-aliasing effect that blurs the edges your image. These pixels that were not removed are not 255! They are a bit lower. Basically you have 2 options:

*(I wrote them from the perspective of using Matlab).*

1. Select the relevant part by using `imfreehand` and then create a mask by calling `createMask` from the API.
2. Finding the correct threshold level, which isn't 255. (Much harder - if possible)

Here is a Matlab code for the first:

```
function SO1
    im = imread('c:\x.jpg');
    figure();
    imshow(im);
    f = imfreehand();
    mask = f.createMask();
    mask = repmat(mask,[1 1 3]);
    im(~mask) = 0;
    figure;imshow(im);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should draw the image to a black background.

```
//Your bitmap
Bitmap originalImage = new Bitmap(100, 100);

//Black background
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

//Draw the background
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 100, 100);

//Draw the original bitmap over the black one
g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

yes.
if your image is save as a variable called img:

```
thr = 255;
mask = sum(img,3)==thr*3;
for i=1:3
    c = img(:,:,i);
    c(mask)=0;
    img(:,:,i)=c;
end
```

|-)

Comment: This algorithm does not solve the problem: the output would be the same as the second image shown in the question.

Comment: Try changing the thr from 255 to somthing smaller
(and the second line to:
mask = sum(img,3)>=thr*3

Comment: Or use distance from background measurement:

thr =200;

img = double(img);

d = (255-img).^2;

d = sqrt(sum(d,3));

d(d>thr)=thr;
d = d/thr;
newImg = img.* repmat(d,[1 1 3]);
image(uint8(newImg));