# PHP Merge images (white color = transparency)

Tags: php, merge, transparency

How to merge images if in image color white get transparency status white color?

**I have this situation:**

[image: http://i31.tinypic.com/2rz5pxc.png]

**I need this result:**

[image]

Comment: You can use PHP GD or ImageMagick. Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried with GD but it will give bad result; the edge of transparent image created with GD won't look smooth, [like this result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iex4s8mxinevimh/Screenshot%202014-07-02%2020.34.36.png).

Comment: hmm i need guidance to start maybe u have something ideas?

Comment: Haven't tried with ImageMagick since I didn't found the method yet. Will give you the result quickly.

Comment: I've tried using ImageMagick and the result is great, very smooth and clean. But we have an issue: since there is part of logo that colored white, it's also removed, [like this result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d3kmc379g9q8dqt/Screenshot%202014-07-02%2021.24.07.png). But if you really don't mind about it, just let me know and I'll write the full answer.

Comment: Nice. very thanks i don't mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a best result, since I didn't know better method to achieve this. Here is my result:

[image: Result Image]

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php

/** Set source image location **/
$baseImageSource    = 'http://q/stock-photos/tux.png';
$overlayImageSource = 'http://q/stock-photos/firefox-logo-small.jpg';

/** Overlay image configuration **/
// Set this value between 0 and 100. 10 will doing great
$fuzz = 10;

// Set position of overlay image, from top and left;
$overlayTop  = 240;
$overlayLeft = 200;


/** Core program **/

// Create Imagick object for source image
$overlayImage = new Imagick( $overlayImageSource );
$finalImage = new Imagick( $baseImageSource );

// Remove overlay image background
$overlayImage->paintTransparentImage(
    $overlayImage->getImagePixelColor( 0, 0 ),
    0, round( $fuzz * 655.35 )
);

// Set image overlay format
$overlayImage->setImageFormat('png');

// Put overlay image to base image
$finalImage->compositeImage(
    $overlayImage, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT,
    $overlayLeft,
    $overlayTop
);

// Set output image format
$finalImage->setImageFormat('png');

// Prepare image and publish!
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $finalImage;
```

Basically this is just a modification of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450999/add-border-around-png-image-using-imagick-php/24527992#24527992) (to achieve image merger) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191749/php-make-image-backgrounds-transparent-with-tolerance) (to achieve background removal). The method used to remove background is [`Imagick::paintTransparentImage()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.painttransparentimage.php), with [`Imagick::getImagePixelColor()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagepixelcolor.php) is used to detect background color. Then we just need to merge both image with [`Imagick::compositeImage()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php).

But still, this result is far from perfect, especially if you compare it with image processing app like GIMP or Photoshop. But you should give it a try. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a program like Gimp, add a transparency layer, delete the white from the firefox image, and save as PNG.