# Create a png image with 2 icons

Tags: php, gd

I want to create image with 2 icons like map marker with profile pic ..

i got a code from google but i dont know how to make with that code

```
$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );
$background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, "thesitewizard.com", $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
?>
```

sample link =
https://localsafedating.com/mapicon.php?g=200

i have  2 part first one is circle and 2nd one is profile pic.  now i want to make a png  picture .

Help me if anyone know about this :) thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Merging two images with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php) or [PHP Merge images (white color = transparency)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529961/php-merge-images-white-color-transparency)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two images with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php)