# remove transparent area (crop transparent) from border using php

Tags: php, image, png, crop

Anybody who help me to solve a problem.
i have image which have transparent area left and right
How to remove transparent area from picture using php.
crop(remove) transparent area from picture 
Note : Gray color is Transparent actually.
[image]

i want convert into  this
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Image background with php and save transparent png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751227/remove-image-background-with-php-and-save-transparent-png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout PHPs `imagecropauto`:

```
resource imagecropauto ( resource $image [, int $mode = -1 [, float $threshold = .5 [, int $color = -1 ]]] )
```

especially:

> IMG_CROP_TRANSPARENT: Crops out a transparent background.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecropauto.php)

Comment: Dear Bro i want crop the image using php