# How to Remove Background of an Img and echo it as a transparent using PHP?

Tags: php

I m trying to remove the background of an image and make it transparent using PHP **without using any 3rd party plugins like ImageMagick** or another.

I came across [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43273641/16356706) in SO itself which promised to echo out transparent background image as result. After trying it did work but I had to define every color in RGB that need to be removed. This is a huge setback as the background colors may vary from image to image as I upload.

**The code I tried:**

```
<?php
$_filename='https://vdofy.harryatwork.com/dev/images-main/images/16330699786156ab99b0c44.png';

$_backgroundColour='0,0,0';
$_img = imagecreatefrompng($_filename);
$_backgroundColours = explode(',', $_backgroundColour);
$_removeColour = imagecolorallocate($_img, (int)$_backgroundColours[0], (int)$_backgroundColours[1], (int)$_backgroundColours[2]);
imagecolortransparent($_img, $_removeColour);
imagesavealpha($_img, true);
$_transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($_img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($_img, 0, 0, $_transColor);
imagepng($_img, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/bg_removed.png");
    
?>
```

Can you guys please share your expertise on making this work?

Comment: I would have thought `imagecreatefrompng` is expecting a `.png` input file, so that call would fail to load a `.jpg`

Comment: @NigelRen tried with a png as well, nothing on the screen.

Comment: Does the file `$_filename` contain the result you are after (this is where the call to `imagepng` will store the output if you specify it)

Comment: @NigelRen no, when I echo the `$_filename` it simply echos the original image url.

Comment: You are trying to _store_ the image to the same URL contained in `$_filename`, that you read it from - that won't work, the HTTP wrapper only allows reading, not writing. You need to store the new image in the local file system. If you need it on a different server - then you will have to upload it to there afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe ok, first of all, Big fan bro. been following you for a long time. And as per my understanding, you are saying is that the above code works but I need to download the generated image into a folder and call it back to echo it instead of re-assigning it to the same var.. right..?

Comment: He means you need to pass a local path to the function in order to store the image e.g. `imagepng($_img, __DIR__ . '/test.png');`

Answer (score 3):

**Final answer**

Your prerequisites `WITHOUT USING ANY PLUGIN` gives as the only option to look for a pixel color based answer. But it is a bad way, because you don't have "color block" images and you can't be sure that a color you're removing is not also in the foreground you want to keep.

The distinction between foreground and background is a human notion and should be processed by an very "clever" plugin. ImageMagick himself fails on your example image :

[image]

---

**First answer**

Here you can remove one of the pixel colors, I arbitrary get one of them and make it transparent with this code :

```
<?php

$_filename='https://vdofy.harryatwork.com/dev/images-main/images/16330699786156ab99b0c44.png';
$im = imagecreatefrompng($_filename);
$remove = imagecolorallocate($im, 208, 216, 218);

imagecolortransparent($im, $remove);

imagepng($im, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/philippe-test.png");
imagedestroy($im);

?>
<body style="background-color: rebeccapurple;">
  <img src="/philippe-test.png">
</body>
```

But I'm afraid you have to make it with **all** the colors to remove, there is no wizard to remove the "background", which is a subjective notion ;)

Comment: But the background color will change from image to image. what we can do on those scenarios

Comment: Yes indeed ! Determining what is the "foreground" in an image can't be solved by removing colors. Cropping what Humans consider as the most interesting part of an image is A.I. hard work.

Answer (score 2):

If the background color is different in other images, you could use `imagecolorat`.

Specify a pixel (`$x` and `$y` in the following code), that has same color as background:

```
<?php

$_filename='https://vdofy.harryatwork.com/dev/images-main/images/16330699786156ab99b0c44.png';
$im = imagecreatefrompng($_filename);

// coordinates of a pixel that has background color
$x = 10;
$y = 10;

$rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;

$remove = imagecolorallocate($im, $r, $g, $b);

imagecolortransparent($im, $remove);

imagepng($im, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/philippe-test.png");
imagedestroy($im);

?>

<body style="background-color: rebeccapurple;">
  <img src="/philippe-test.png">
</body>
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php