# How do we remove image white background color using PHP Code

Tags: php, image, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Translate Ruby into PHP code with the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207639/translate-ruby-into-php-code-with-the-following-code)

I found a very useful Ruby code on to remove image white background color.

Please see reference code below:
[Remove white background from an image and make it transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041703/remove-white-background-from-an-image-and-make-it-transparent?answertab=active#tab-top)

I tried to translate the code into php. However I am getting an unwanted result. This is my first time post question here, can someone please give me some guideline and forgive my poor English.

```
function setTransparency($new_image,$image_source) 
{         
    $transparencyIndex = imagecolortransparent($image_source); 
    $transparencyColor = array('red' => 255, 'green' => 255, 'blue' => 255); 

    if ($transparencyIndex >= 0) { 
        $transparencyColor = imagecolorsforindex($image_source, $transparencyIndex);    
    } 

    $transparencyIndex = imagecolorallocate($new_image, $transparencyColor['red'], $transparencyColor['green'], $transparencyColor['blue']); 
    imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $transparencyIndex); 
    imagecolortransparent($new_image, $transparencyIndex); 

}

//create image from the source link
$image = imagecreatefrompng('https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7E1F.png');

//create image mask layer
$new_image = ImageCreateTruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));

//remove white background 
setTransparency($new_image,$image); 

//merge mask with original image source
ImageCopyMerge($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image), 100);

imagejpeg($new_image, null, 95);
```

Comment: Your link refers to a Mathematica solution, not Ruby. You'll want to look into using ImageMagick: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php  Here is another question that includes an ImageMagick solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738437/rmagick-remove-white-background-from-image-and-make-it-transparent

Comment: this is not a duplicate question, he wanted to implement Mark Ransom's algorithm using the actual php library, you've posted some commandline utility which is not related to Mark Ransom's algorithm at all

Answer (score 5):

The JPEG format does not support transparency. You should consider to use png as output format. Change the last line to:

```
imagepng($new_image, null, 9);
```